# How to handle chinese charactor when getting user input from stdin using getline

Tags: c++, getline

I try to get user input using getline fucntion. User may type chinese charactors, some backspaces and some other charactors. Then I meet an issue. What I get in program is not I typed in termial.

My code likes below:

int main(int argc, chart argv[])
{

```
cout << ">>";
char *cmdBuf = (char*)malloc(1024);
while(true)
{    
    size_t cmdLen = 1024;   
    ssize_t readNum = getline(&cmdBuf, &cmdLen, stdin);
    if (readNum == -1 || readNum == 1)   
    {    
         cout << ">>";
         continue;
    }
    cout << "readNum: " << readNum << ". The input is: << cmdBuf;
    cout << ">>;  
}

free(cmdBuf) ; 
return 0;
```

}

Execute the program in shell and get the results below('在' is a chinese charactor):

user input: **display**
program output: **readNum: 8. The input is: display**

user input: **display在**
program output: **readNum: 11．The input is：display在**

user input: **display在[backspace][backspace]**   ----------------- The termial shows "display".
program output: **readNum: 9. The input is: display[a garbled character]**

user input: **display在[backspace][backspace][backspace]** ----------------- The termial shows "displa".
program output: **readNum: 8. The input is: display**
[image]

From the results, '在' contains 3 charactors. However, if I type '在', I only need type 2 backspaces to clear '在' and then I will get a wrong input in C++ program.

What should I do to make sure what C++ program get from stdin is what user see in the terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I cin and cout some unicode text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207704/how-can-i-cin-and-cout-some-unicode-text)

Comment: It depends on your OS and compiler.

Comment: I use SUSE os. Do I need to modify some os configuration to fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73052441/backspace-and-multibyte-characters-using-getchar-in-c TL;DR type `stty iutf8` at the command line and try again.